# How to change layout of sap.uxap.ObjectPage Blocks

Tags: sapui5

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zDaBJtGcfyIUfdRwS3Oc?p=preview)

I have 2 + 5 blocks here, in small screen, each panel in blocks are in full width.

[image]

But in large screen, blocks are in 3:3:3 or 6:3. I want them all in a single row.

[image]

each section is contained in `<div class="sapUiRespGridSpanL4 sapUiRespGridSpanM6 sapUiRespGridSpanS12 sapUiRespGridSpanXL3">`

How to change it to `class="sapUiRespGridSpanL12 sapUiRespGridSpanM12 sapUiRespGridSpanS12 sapUiRespGridSpanXL12"` ?

I've tried to add layout in `Panel`, but not working.

Refrence:

[sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2e61ab6c68a2480eb666c1927a707658)

[layout of blocks, blocks are in the same color, hard to specify](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.uxap.sample.ObjectPageSubSectionMultiView/preview)

Comment: Just as a side note: the app in the provided demo is expanding infinitely. In order to prevent this, put the ObjectPageLayout into a root element E.g.: `<App><uxap:ObjectPageLayout>...</uxap:ObjectPageLayout></App>`

Comment: Thanks for mention that. In my app, there is a `App.view.xml` work as App container, I forgot to paste it in my sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Finally after 1.5 hours figured out*

Reason: [Blocks](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/4527729576cb4a4888275b6935aad03a) will have to be extended from BlockBase to apply columnLayout.

**Extending the BlockBase:**

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/uxap/BlockBase"], function (BlockBase) {
    "use strict";

    var BlockPanel = BlockBase.extend("sap.uxap.sample.ObjectPageSubSectionSized.blocks.BlockPanel", {
        metadata: {
            /* no additional views provided */
        }
    });
    return BlockPanel;
});
```

Then create a view and controller using the above new ui5 extended control. Use that in your page with columnLayout

```
xmlns:sample="sap.uxap.sample.ObjectPageSubSectionSized.blocks"
...
...
<uxap:blocks>
   <sample:BlockPanel columnLayout="4"/>        
</uxap:blocks>
```

columnLayout can't be applied if you don't extend block base. (which is really pathetic design). Nevertheless, values range from `1-4` and `"auto"`.

[Created working plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UndiLhnLvokXQzxgBl1z?p=preview)

[How to build custom SAPUI control?](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db)

Comment: Nice explanation. So I need to create 2 + 5 xml view here? Impressive.

Comment: Just as a side note: There is a `.sapUxAPBlockBase {min-height: 8rem}` class in BlockBase which causes huge gap between panels.

Comment: I rarely use Custom Controls, also add [Custom Controls Doc](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db) as a reference.

Comment: hmm, this should have been straight forward! Don't know why they have implemented like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the target controls up with `sap.uxap.BlockBase`<sup>[[API]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.BlockBase)</sup>. BlockBase controls are intended to be used inside `sap.uxap.ObjectPageSubSection` (hence the name `<blocks>`) and support customizing the grid spans with the property `columnLayout`.

Here is a demo: https://embed.plnkr.co/lSrDk9/?show=view%2FHome.view.xml,preview

```xml
<uxap:ObjectPageSubSection>
  <block:MyBlock columnLayout="4"/>
  <block:MyBlock columnLayout="4"/>
</uxap:ObjectPageSubSection>
```

Comment: @SunilBN Sorry ;) But I think you explained more thoroughly. +1!

Comment: Hahaha. Thanks. My SAPUI5 skills are rusted. Its been 2 years so since I wrote. So took lot of time to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a not elegant, but very fast way: Overwrite CSS

```
<uxap:ObjectPageSubSection class="fullWidthPanel">

/* CSS specificity */
.fullWidthPanel .sapUiRespGrid.sapUiRespGridHSpace1 > div {
  width: 98.88888889%;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 1rem);
  width: calc(100% - 1rem)
}
```